# how to quicklisp package in CGI

Tags: apache2, cgi, clisp, quicklisp

My quicklisp script (shown below) works very well, but in Apache2 it doesn't work.  Maybe Apache2 can't load the `.clisprc.lisp` file?

I have tried installing the packages named `lisp-cgi-utils` and `pg`.

Any advice on including a quicklisp module in CGI would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/clisp
(load "/home/kimbom/.clisprc.lisp")
(with-open-file
(standard-output "/dev/null" :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
(ql:quickload "lisp-cgi-utils")
(ql:quickload "pg"))

(format t "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8~%~%~%")
(princ (html:html-header "html.lisp example page"))

(princ (html:body
(html:h1 "test page for html.lisp package")
(html:h2 "lists")
(html:ul
(html:li "first entry")
(html:li "second entry"))
(html:p "a simple paragraph" " and more text")
(html:p '((class . "tester")) "another one")))
(princ (html:html-footer))

(bye)
```